# How to Arrangement array before send request to alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, alamofire

```
let request = NSMutableDictionary()
request.setDictionary([ "merchant_reference":getRandomMerchant, "merchant_identifier":"e54638eb", "access_code":"hRRVGXrIpHSYoH19Ebwt", "signature": base64Str, "service_command":"OTP_GENERATE", "language":"en", "payment_option":"VALU", "phone_number":"01008606003", "merchant_order_id":getRandomMerchant, "amount":getTotal, "currency":"EGP", "products":[ [ "product_name": getName, "product_price": getTotal, "product_category":getProductType ] ] ])

Alamofire.request(URLAPi.URL_Payment_Api ,
                  method : .post ,
                  parameters : (request as! Parameters) ,
                  encoding: JSONEncoding.default
).responseJSON { (response) in
    debugPrint(response)
    if response.result.isSuccess {
        let jsonpayfortrequest : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
        var resultsArray = jsonpayfortrequest.arrayValue
        var sortedResults = resultsArray.sorted { $0.stringValue > $1.stringValue }
        print(jsonpayfortrequest)
        print(resultsArray)
        print(sortedResults)
        print(jsonpayfortrequest.sorted(by: {$0 > $1}))
        let passobjectforrootclasspayfort = OTPGenrateModel(fromJson: jsonpayfortrequest)
        print(passobjectforrootclasspayfort.transaction_id!)
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

    } else {
        print("error connection") SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

    }

}
```

Comment: //                            "product_category" = 1;
                    //                           "product_name" = kston27SZL660;
                    //                           "product_price" = 265000;
                                
                    //                            "product_name" = kston27SZL660;
                                       //                           "product_name" = 1;
                                       //                           "product_price" = 265000;

Comment: I need when every send request object become this same arrangement.                                  product_name.    product_price.    product_category

Comment: Your question is unclear. "before"? Could you edit your question with current output, and target output?

Comment: every time when send request to json this object  [
                        "product_name": getName,
                        "product_price": getTotal,
                        "product_category":getProductType

                    ].                                                                                                             
 every time send request to json this object change in arrangements  objects  like that product_category.  product_pirce product_name   and another become product_price product_name product_category and

Comment: i dont need that i need become product_name.  product_price  product_category   finally when send request to json need this arrangements.   product_name.  product_price  product_category

Comment: It's a Dictionary, you shouldn't care about order. It's key-access, not index-access...

Comment: okay, what can i do to make this sort becuase i send this request three times to get this structure  product_name. product_price product_category , so backend must be handle  this json from your side ! or what ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way, Hope, that will fixe your issue. If it doesn't, please reply

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "merchant_reference":getRandomMerchant,
            "merchant_identifier":"e54638eb",
            "access_code":"hRRVGXrIpHSYoH19Ebwt",
            "signature": base64Str,
            "service_command":"OTP_GENERATE",
            "language":"en",
            "payment_option":"VALU",
            "phone_number":"01008606003",
            "merchant_order_id":getRandomMerchant,
            "amount":getTotal,
            "currency":"EGP",
            "products": [
                    [
                    "product_name": getName,
                    "product_price": getTotal,
                    "product_category":getProductType
                    ]
                ]
        ]

        Alamofire.request(URLAPi.URL_Payment_Api , method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON {  response in
                print(response)


                // Insert your code here
        }
```

Comment: [
                 "product_name": getName,
                 "product_price": getTotal,
                 "product_category":getProductType
            ] how to make this object always print this arrange every send request

Comment: Yes I need that because when send request items this object change arrangements for example become     [ "product_price": getTotal, "product_category":getProductType, "product_name": getName ]  and another become  [ "product_category":getProductType, "product_price": getTotal, "product_name": getName ]   so i need when send request every time this object become like that arrangment  [ "product_name": getName, "product_price": getTotal, "product_category":getProductType ]

Comment: I have updated the Answer to print products.  But It's a dictionary while making an API request, the dictionary's order doesn't matter at all.

Comment: not work i think this json must be handle from backend developer

Comment: Well, can you check the recently edited answer? and please let me know.
and what is your Alamofire version?